# Flutter : Is provider an alternative to the BLoC pattern?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-provider

I know that BLoC in flutter acts like the viewmodel layer in android's MVVM, so the data does not gets fetched again and again upon configuration changes (for ex: change in screen orientation).

I am confused if [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) replaces the functionality of RxDart in BLoC pattern or it replaces the role BLoC pattern itself.

Also, if I don't use BLoC at all  an only providers does the app survives configuration changes.

Please explain what are the limitations of provider over BLoC, RxDart combination with some use cases.

Comment: "Provider is a dependency injection system built with widgets for widgets. provider is mostly syntax sugar for InheritedWidget, to make common use-cases straightforward." - BLoC is a pattern. They can be combined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Provider in itself doesn't replace the BLoC pattern. However, you can set up your architecture to use Provider in a way that could replace the BLoC pattern.

One way to do that would be to use the MVVM pattern, where you have a view model class that [extends a ChangeNotifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56680226/should-you-use-extends-or-with-keyword-for-changenotifier-flutter). Then you can listen to that view model with a [ChangeNotifierProvider](https://medium.com/flutter-community/making-sense-all-of-those-flutter-providers-e842e18f45dd) so that the UI gets rebuilt any time the view model changes. FilledStacks does that well [here](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-architecture-my-provider-implementation-guide/).

See also

- [A beginner’s guide to architecting a Flutter app](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-beginners-guide-to-architecting-a-flutter-app-1e9053211a74)
- [State Management With Provider](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6373413-state-management-with-provider)

Personally I find it easier to use the builtin Flutter tools to manage state. I describe that more here:

- [Flutter state management for minimalists](https://suragch.medium.com/flutter-state-management-for-minimalists-4c71a2f2f0c1?sk=6f9cedfb550ca9cc7f88317e2e7055a0)