# Should you use "extends" or "with" keyword for ChangeNotifier? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, state

I have seen several examples of a model extending ChangeNotifier using both 'extends' and 'with' keywords. I am not sure what the difference is.

```
class myModel extends ChangeNotifier {...}

class myModel with ChangeNotifier {...}
```

What is the difference between those two? Which one should I use?

Comment: see [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/https-medium-com-shubhamhackzz-dart-for-flutter-mixins-in-dart-f8bb10a3d341) and  [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use either `extends` (to inherit) or `with` (as a mixin). Both ways give you access to the `notifyListeners()` method in `ChangeNotifier`.

### Inheritance

Extending `ChangeNotifier` means that `ChangeNotifier` is the super class.

```dart
class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  
  String someValue = 'Hello';
  
  void doSomething(String value) {
    someValue = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

If your model class is already extending another class, then you can't extend `ChangeNotifier` because Dart does not allow multiple inheritance. In this case you must use a mixin.

### Mixin

A mixin allows you to use the concrete methods of the mixin class (ie, `notifyListeners()`).

```dart
class MyModel with ChangeNotifier {
  
  String someValue = 'Hello';
  
  void doSomething(String value) {
    someValue = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

So even if your model already extends from another class, you can still "mix in" `ChangeNotifier`.

```
class MyModel extends SomeOtherClass with ChangeNotifier {
  
  String someValue = 'Hello';
  
  void doSomething(String value) {
    someValue = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here are some good reads about mixins:

- [Dart: What are mixins?](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3)
- [Dart for Flutter : Mixins in Dart](https://medium.com/flutter-community/https-medium-com-shubhamhackzz-dart-for-flutter-mixins-in-dart-f8bb10a3d341)

Comment: So, why Flutter provide extending, while we always can use mixin?

Comment: You can mixin any class. A class doesn't have to be annotated as a mixin to be a Mixin.

Answer (score 8):

`extends` is used to **inherit** a class
`with` is used to use class as a **mixin**

Refer here to understand difference between **mixin** and **inheritence**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/860312/10471480

Refering to [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html), the docs says

> A class that can be extended or mixed in that provides a change notification API using VoidCallback for notifications.

Hence you can inherit it as well as use it as a mixin

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with legacy support. The mixin keyword was introduced in Dart 2.1.0. According to the documentation, you should [AVOID mixing in a type that isn’t intended to be a mixin](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-mixing-in-a-class-that-isnt-intended-to-be-a-mixin):

> For compatibility reasons, Dart still allows you to mix in classes
> that aren’t defined using mixin. But, that’s risky. If the author of
> the class doesn’t intend the class to be used as a mixin, they might
> change the class in a way that breaks the mixin restrictions. For
> example, if they add a constructor, your class will break.
>
> If the class doesn’t have a doc comment or an obvious name like
> IterableMixin, assume you cannot mix in the class if it isn’t declared
> using mixin.

As Dart does not allow multiple inheritances the ChangeNotifier API allows it to be mixed in. As the documentation states:

> A class that can be extended or mixed in that provides a change
> notification API using VoidCallback for notifications.

IMHO to be aligned to the language specification Flutter should change the ChangeNotifier, separating those reusable implementations into Mixin Classes. At least the Dart documentation makes me think this is something that could not be supported anymore in a future release [the mix in of a non mixin class].

There are lot of discussions around this:

- [Make ChangeNotifier a mixin](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40808)
- [Allow mixins in "extends" clauses](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1942)

Answer (score 0):

in **Provider**, Both allow to use notifyListeners(),But

Extend means that (ChangeNotifier) is superclass,
Mixin allows using the methods from (ChangeNotifier) class

also
You can **extend** one class
But can **mixin** more than one class

This is a good short article about difference:
[Should use Extends or Mixin | Flutter Tips](https://www.ifeps.net/2022/04/should-i-use-extends-or-mixin-with.html)